# Is it possible to record sound from the TRRS jack?

Tags: java, android, audio, record, recording

From what I've read it doesn't seem possible to record from anything past the mic:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html

Ideally I'd like to be able to record from the TRRS jack, as I have a 3.5mm to RCA cable that I hook up to my mixer. I figured there has to be a way to make it think that the cable is really a headset (maybe a TRRS to 2 x TRS splitter?) so that it doesn't attempt to record from the built-in mic, but I haven't found a solution.